# UV and Imported Meshes from Collada file

Tags: uv, collada

I am working with some simple geometric characters designed in Sketchup and imported into Blender via a .DAE file. When I try to mark seams to get geometry to unpack correctly, I don't see a difference in the UV - it doesn't show connected faces and edges correctly. However, when I redraw the same shape in Blender (i.e. cube drawn over imported cube), then I can mark seams and get correct unfolding behavior. So I would like to avoid re-drawing everything and get the right behavior from my imported model, which I cleaned and simplified. Thanks for any suggestions to address this.

Comment: can you add some screen captures showing the details of the problem? It's difficult to tell from just your description what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the cube model from SketchUp the 6 faces are not connected to each other, meaning instead of one vertex at each corner there are 3. This means that whether you have marked seams or not it will always unwrap as 6 separate UV islands. You mentioned that you did a clean-up so just checking to see that that also included using the merge tool to merge the 3 vertices at each corner so that they become 1. In **Edit mode** with every thing selected > **Mesh** > **Merge** > **By Distance**.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this. Thank you for the explanation and solution.

Comment: Consider to accept it though @CharlieT See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers